# Using cucumber reporters with the protractor-cucumber-framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, teamcity

As far as I understand, the `protractor-cucumber-framework` passes through the `cucumberOpts` object to cucumber, which allows the user to specify cucumber options like `strict` and `tags`. I'm trying to use a TeamCity reporter with this framework. According to the instructions for the reporters, (e.g. [TeamCity Reporter](https://github.com/kevinrood/teamcity_formatter), to use this reporter you use the `--format` option to specify the reporter when running cucumber. So my interpretation is that I should specify the `format` property in the `cucumberOpts` object in the same way. i.e. `cucumber -f TeamCityFormatter::Formatter` becomes:

```
cucumberOpts: {
  'format': 'TeamCityFormatter::Formatter'
}
```

But when I do this, I get the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Dev\fork\Billing.Test.Automation.V2\:Formatter':
```

I thought maybe I just need to specify the name of the module, so I tried:

```
cucumberOpts: {
  'format': 'TeamCityFormatter'
}
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Dev\fork\Billing.Test.Automation.V2\TeamCityFormatter'
```

So that looks like it is looking for a module, so I tried pointing it to the module in the `node_modules` folder:

```
cucumberOpts: {
  'format': 'node_modules/teamcity-formatter'
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: this.registerHandler is not a function
```

Is there some special way to use a cucumber reporter via the `protractor-cucumber-framework`?

Comment: You are looking at a ruby package instead of a nodeJS package. There does seem to be a similar node package called [cucumber-teamcity-formatter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-json-to-teamcity) which may work for you.

Comment: That package is used to convert the json file produced at the end of the testing into teamcity messages, not to report the test results in teamcity format during execution. The package I used was an example, all other similar packages have similar errors. But thanks all the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a better understanding of this area myself but I've posted an example of how a package can be imported as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an example of how a package can be imported as a plugin

```
onPrepare:fucntion(){
  ...
},
// Here the magic happens
plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
    options: {
        automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
        removeExistingJsonReportFile: true,
        displayDuration: true
    }
}],
```